# The meaning of "become of"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

I encountered a sentence in the [Oxford Dictionaries' definition of *dead*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dead):

> ‘higher up, the marble **becomes of** a dull, dead colour’

The phrasal verb **become of** doesn't make sense here. According to the dictionaries I have just checked, it is usually used with "what" and means "happen to." I thought the sentence above would work better with **becomes** (without **of**). What does **become of** mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Higher up, the marble becomes a dull, dead colour.

This would mean that the marble transforms into a colour, which is odd.

We have three ways of describing the color of the marble:

> 1) The colour of the marble is dull and dead.
>   2) The marble is of a dull, dead colour.
>   3) The marble has a dull, dead colour.

We can use the word **becomes** in the first two structures:

> 1) The colour of the marble **becomes** dull and dead.
>   2) The marble **becomes of** a dull, dead colour.

But not in the last structure.

Thus,

> 1) Higher up, the color of the marble **becomes** dull and dead.
>   2) Higher up, the marble **becomes of** a dull, dead color.

Comment: So basically, *become of* is not a phrasal verb here, but a verb and a preposition?

Comment: @L.Moneta - yes

Comment: +1.  This locution is now a fossil. Charles Darwin may have used it, but it has  since evolved into **turns (into)**.